# I need this SQL statement in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Is it possible to delete multiple rows via JPA in a database table via a specific ID?

e.g.

```
Delete from PERSON_LANGUAGE where PERSON_ID = 125;
```

Thanks in advance!

Down below is what im currently trying to use without any luck!

```
public void deletePersonLanguageById(PersonLanguage personLanguage){
    PersonLanguage personLanguage1 = em.find(PersonLanguage.class, personLanguage.getPersonId());
    em.remove(personLanguage1);
}
```

I want it to delete everything in my databasetable where the `ID = 1`

Comment: The Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL) is a platform-independent object-oriented query language defined as part of the Java Persistence API (JPA) specification. JPQL is used to make queries and execute database commands against entities stored in a relational database.

Comment: A delete query would bypass JPA. This is a bad idea except for bulk delete.
Your attempt seems to be correct. Are you using JTA? If not, did you forget to commit the transaction?

Comment: It seems that you have a PersonLanguage object as a parameter and you're trying to remove a PersonLanguage that have as ID the personID of the parameter, could be a logical error because the find return another element or don't find any. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [native query](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/ExecuteNativeQuery.htm) to execute SQL directly against your database

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM person_language WHERE person_id = 1");
q.executeUpdate();
```

or a JPQL query:

```
Query q = em.creteQuery("DELETE FROM Person p WHERE p.personId = 1");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Karol you could improve your answer with a dynamic parameter.
Nico, the answer of Karol is also JPA, maybe you're refering to CriteriaQuery as a form that you have to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom repository that extends from the JPA Repository and there you add the `deleteByPersonId(String personId)`.

Some more examples here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details